# What is general fluid intelligence?

Tags: intelligence, working-memory

I'm currently reading about executive control, a lot of papers (e.g. [Kane and Engle 2002](http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.3758/BF03196323.pdf)) discuss general fluid intelligence but don't explain it. **What is general fluid intelligence?**

Answer (score 4):

Just did some more reading, going to answer my own question:

> Fluid intelligence (Gf) refers to mental operations that an individual uses when faced with a relatively novel task that cannot be performed automatically. Inductive and deductive reasoning are generally thought to be the hallmark narrow-ability indicators of Gf. Examples of Gf abilities are: Induction, Pigatian Reasoning, Quantitative Reasoning and Speed of Reasoning.

By comparison Crystallized Intelligence (Gc):

> Gc refers to the breadth and depth of a persons acquired knowledge, and the application of this knowledge. Examples of Gc abilities are: Language Development, Lexical Knowledge, General Information, Information about Culture, General Science Information, Communication Abilities etc..

Reference:
Reynolds, C. R., & Fletcher-Janzen, E. (2007). Encyclopedia of Special Education (Vol. 1). Wiley.

If anyone has anything better or more to add, please do.